# linux perf: how to get IBS support?

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, amd-processor

I have a AMD Epyc processor based machine with Linux kernel 4.19.71 running. I was trying to run some performance tuning using IBS (instruction-based sampling) events, with used `perf` tool from `$linux/tools/perf`. Based on what I searched, it *should* be possible to just pass `-e ibs_fetch` or `-e ibs_op` arguments to `perf`, however mine seems don't accept it, claiming as parsing error. On the other hand, `/sys/bus/event_source/devices` does show `ibs_fetch` and `ibs_op` events available, which means both the hardware and the kernel support it.

May be perf has to be compiled with some options to get IBS support compile in, or do I need a higher version of perf.

**UPDATE 1**

After more careful reading of `man perf-list`, I realize that PMU requires "slash" symbol following the PMU name (thanks @Hadi Brais for pointing this out). However :

```
% perf stat -a -e ibs_fetch// -I 1000
#           time             counts unit events
     1.000171849    <not supported>      ibs_fetch//                                     
     2.000326745    <not supported>      ibs_fetch//                                     
     3.000526938    <not supported>      ibs_fetch//                                     
     4.000753021    <not supported>      ibs_fetch//
```

Also:

```
%  perf record -a -e ibs_fetch// -p `pidof qemu-system-x86_64` -R
Warning:
PID/TID switch overriding SYSTEM
Error:
The sys_perf_event_open() syscall returned with 22 (Invalid argument) for event (ibs_fetch//).
/bin/dmesg | grep -i perf may provide additional information.

%
%
% /bin/dmesg | grep -i perf
[    0.149465] Performance Events: Fam17h core perfctr, AMD PMU driver.
[   10.523189] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[   10.529792] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[   10.535156] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[   10.540522] AMD-Vi: IOMMU performance counters supported
[   11.241808] perf: AMD IBS detected (0x000003ff)
[   11.246388] perf/amd_iommu: Detected AMD IOMMU #0 (2 banks, 4 counters/bank).
[   11.253584] perf/amd_iommu: Detected AMD IOMMU #1 (2 banks, 4 counters/bank).
[   11.261628] perf/amd_iommu: Detected AMD IOMMU #2 (2 banks, 4 counters/bank).
[   11.268828] perf/amd_iommu: Detected AMD IOMMU #3 (2 banks, 4 counters/bank).
[  549.446621] perf: interrupt took too long (7809 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
[ 1827.711752] INFO: NMI handler (perf_event_nmi_handler) took too long to run: 1.216 msecs
[ 2077.214530] perf: interrupt took too long (10051 > 9761), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 19000
%
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
% perf record -R -a -e ibs_fetch//pp sleep 1
..
%
% perf report -D --stdio --header
# ========
# captured on    : Fri Jan 15 14:44:13 2021
# header version : 1
# data offset    : 1256
# data size      : 2666080
# feat offset    : 2667336
# hostname : ESA-1
# os release : 4.19.71
# perf version :
# arch : x86_64
# nrcpus online : 128
# nrcpus avail : 128
# cpudesc : AMD EPYC 7702P 64-Core Processor
# cpuid : AuthenticAMD,23,49,0
# total memory : 528164320 kB
# cmdline : /usr/bin/perf record -R -a -e ibs_fetch//pp sleep 1
# event : name = ibs_fetch//pp, , id = { 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277,
 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293,
 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309,
 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325,
 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341,
 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357,
 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373,
374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389,
 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397 }, type = 10, size = 112, { sample_perio
d, sample_freq } = 4000, sample_type = IP|TID|TIME|CPU|PERIOD|RAW, read_format =
 ID, disabled = 1, inherit = 1, mmap = 1, comm = 1, freq = 1, task = 1, precise_
ip = 2, sample_id_all = 1, comm_exec = 1
# CPU_TOPOLOGY info available, use -I to display
# NUMA_TOPOLOGY info available, use -I to display
# pmu mappings: amd_df = 8, software = 1, ibs_op = 11, amd_iommu_2 = 14, ibs_fet
ch = 10, uprobe = 7, cpu = 4, amd_iommu_0 = 12, breakpoint = 5, amd_l3 = 9, trac
epoint = 2, amd_iommu_3 = 15, kprobe = 6, amd_iommu_1 = 13, msr = 16
# CACHE info available, use -I to display
# time of first sample : 670.575018
# time of last sample : 671.580647
# sample duration :   1005.629 ms
# missing features: TRACING_DATA BRANCH_STACK GROUP_DESC AUXTRACE STAT MEM_TOPOL
OGY
# ========
#
...
<raw events dump>
...
Aggregated stats:
           TOTAL events:      31423
            MMAP events:        166
            LOST events:          0
            COMM events:       1663
            EXIT events:          1
        THROTTLE events:         92
      UNTHROTTLE events:          2
            FORK events:       1661
            READ events:          0
          SAMPLE events:      27512
           MMAP2 events:        320
             AUX events:          0
    ITRACE_START events:          0
    LOST_SAMPLES events:          0
          SWITCH events:          0
 SWITCH_CPU_WIDE events:          0
      NAMESPACES events:          0
            ATTR events:          0
      EVENT_TYPE events:          0
    TRACING_DATA events:          0
        BUILD_ID events:          0
  FINISHED_ROUND events:          3
        ID_INDEX events:          0
   AUXTRACE_INFO events:          0
        AUXTRACE events:          0
  AUXTRACE_ERROR events:          0
      THREAD_MAP events:          1
         CPU_MAP events:          1
     STAT_CONFIG events:          0
            STAT events:          0
      STAT_ROUND events:          0
    EVENT_UPDATE events:          0
       TIME_CONV events:          1
         FEATURE events:          0
ibs_fetch//pp stats:
           TOTAL events:      27512
            MMAP events:          0
            LOST events:          0
            COMM events:          0
            EXIT events:          0
        THROTTLE events:          0
      UNTHROTTLE events:          0
            FORK events:          0
            READ events:          0
          SAMPLE events:      27512
           MMAP2 events:          0
             AUX events:          0
    ITRACE_START events:          0
    LOST_SAMPLES events:          0
          SWITCH events:          0
 SWITCH_CPU_WIDE events:          0
      NAMESPACES events:          0
            ATTR events:          0
      EVENT_TYPE events:          0
    TRACING_DATA events:          0
        BUILD_ID events:          0
  FINISHED_ROUND events:          0
        ID_INDEX events:          0
   AUXTRACE_INFO events:          0
        AUXTRACE events:          0
  AUXTRACE_ERROR events:          0
      THREAD_MAP events:          0
         CPU_MAP events:          0
     STAT_CONFIG events:          0
            STAT events:          0
      STAT_ROUND events:          0
    EVENT_UPDATE events:          0
       TIME_CONV events:          0
         FEATURE events:          0
%
```

Comment: It sounds to me you have syntax error in the perf command itself. Show the full command you're using. The syntax `-e ibs_fetch` is only valid if `ibs_fetch` is an event, which it isn't. It's a perf PMU, which means the correct syntax is `-e ibs_fetch//` You also need the `-R` option if you want to capture the fields you asked for in the previous question. Then dump the raw trace using `perf report -D` to get the samples, which can be parsed manually or using a script.

Comment: @HadiBrais, thanks for feedback. I updated the question.

Comment: `ibs_fetch//` and `ibs_op//` can only be used in sampling mode, not counting mode. So try with `perf record -R` as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Hmm, try maybe `perf record -R -a -e ibs_op//pp sleep 1` or `perf record -R -a -e ibs_fetch//pp sleep 1`. Note that you can't specify both `-p` and `-a` switches. The warning is telling you that `-p` overrides `-a`. Unfortunately, I currently don't have access to an AMD system to check what works.

Comment: @HadiBrais, thanks for comment. I updated my question. It seems that ibs_fetch PMU does report counters, if I understand the output of `perf report` output?

Comment: Nice, it's working now. I think it requires the `pp` modifier. Try the previous command but with `pp` like this: `perf record -a -e ibs_fetch//pp -p `pidof qemu-system-x86_64` -R` and see if it works. But choose either `-p` or `-a`, not both.

Comment: @HadiBrais, `perf record -e ibs_fetch//pp -p $APP_PID -R` fails with the same error as before. The same failure happens if I run `perf record ... -t $thread_id ...`, so it seems to be more fundamental problem. BTW, `man perf-record` does not mention that `-p` and `-a` can't be used together. How did know this?

Comment: I think the perf_event subsystem only supports IBS sampling in system-wide mode i.e., the `-a` switch is required. That's why it's not working with `-p` or `-t`. Regarding how did I know that `-p` and `-a` can't be used together,I looked at the source code. AMD has a set of tools called the [AMD IBS Toolkit](https://github.com/jlgreathouse/AMD_IBS_Toolkit), which also only support system-wide sampling.